# Request failed with status code 401 com.google.step_count.delta

Tags: google-fit

{"message":"Request failed with status code 401","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Request failed with status code 401\n    at createError (/home/user/Projects/HealthBlock/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (/home/user/Projects/HealthBlock/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/user/Projects/HealthBlock/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)","config":{"url":"https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate","method":"post","data":"{"aggregateBy":[{"dataTypeName":"com.google.step_count.delta","dataSourceId":"derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"}],"bucketByTime":{"durationMillis":86400000},"startTimeMillis":1585785599000,"endTimeMillis":1585958399000}","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","authorization":"Bearerya29.a0ARrdaM8Rx7JTevizLGoMkJYBqAGba27LtAQKbnodcgXsqkUFVyBFgm4ZNAvci84LbiowSnmpNxFhGCKcq1UKk6819L37kd1HPPbeXNsrmrbPjZu6pM7Jsw9p7xIwsMJLYZFrg4lNkgoPbMOFA5ZIlY021C0C","User-Agent":"axios/0.21.1","Content-Length":261},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"Content-Type":"application/json"}}

Comment: 401 means authorization required. At a glance, I notice your authorization header is lacking a space after "Bearer"; see https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/first-app#send-an-http-request for example.

Answer (score 0):

401 error response status code indicates that the client request has not been completed. Double check your credentials (i.e. client ID and client secret) are correct and there are no blank spaces.